# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 421 (Bad Request)

Tags: javascript, html, ios, web-services, cloudkit

I am using Apple's new CloudKit JS reference and sample code to build a simple CRUD app. Before I can even get to CRUD however I am being stopped by Apple authentication.

```
index.html
<html>
<body>

<div id="apple-sign-in-button">Sign in
       <span id="username"></span>
</div>

<script>
    /*
     * Initialize the global objects we will need.
     */
    if(typeof CKCatalog === 'undefined') {
        CKCatalog = {};
    }

    if(typeof CKCatalog.tabs === 'undefined') {
        CKCatalog.tabs = {
            'readme': [{}],
            'not-found': [{}]
        };
    }
</script>

<script src="js/init.js"></script>
<script src="js/cloudkit-code-samples/authentication.js"></script>
<script>
    window.addEventListener('cloudkitloaded',CKCatalog.init);
</script>
<script async src="https://cdn.apple-cloudkit.com/ck/1/cloudkit.js">    </script>

</body>
```

Including div id="apple-sign-in-button" and span id="username" got rid of all errors except:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 421 (Bad Request).

Any mention of this error anywhere else usually has it tied to SMTP or FTP. Any idea what is going on?

Comment: I'm getting the exact same error. and I even tried to serve a ssl cert, without luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The CloudKit.js library is a wrapper around the CloudKit Web Services, and [its documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloutKitWebServicesReference/ErrorCodes/ErrorCodes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015240-CH4-SW1) states that an HTTP 421 happens when a request was called that required authentication, but the user was not logged in.

This is expected as your app will likely need to determine if a user is logged in and, if not, show the appropriate Sign In button. The [CloudKit Catalog example's section on Authentication](https://cdn.apple-cloudkit.com/cloudkit-catalog/#authentication) shows how you can set this up by calling `container.setUpAuth()`, which will check for a user and render the Sign In button if none is detected. It's possible that this is happening in your init.js code, but without seeing it I can't be sure.

I see you have the `apple-sign-in-button` div on your page. If you're calling the `setUpAuth` method then you should see the Sign In button rendered inside of it.

Once a user clicks that button and signs in then you can re-issue the original request that was receiving a 421 and should get a valid 200.

Don't forget that if you want to persist the user's CloudKit session you can use `auth: { persist: true }` when you initialize your Container (see the CloudKit.js docs for more).

You'll also want to ensure you've created an API token in the CloudKit Dashboard for your Container. This is the token you use when you initialize your Container. Check out the WWDC 2015 video on CloudKit JS and Web Services to see a demo of this.

I hope that helps!

UPDATE:

**When testing your web application, make sure that you've configured your API Token (using the CloudKit Dashboard) to allow for the domain you're testing with (e.g. localhost). This was originally Sam's problem but localhost is now a supported domain for API tokens in the Development Environment.**

Comment: Hi David thx for replying. The Error Code documentation which I overlooked was helpful as was your perspective. Just an FYI I did set up a token + my container name in init.js as well as persist: true. I see that setupAuth (in authentication.js) was called however the button is never generated, and what happens after setupAuth is called is the function goToUnauthenticatedState is called. Is there another <div> I have to construct in my index.html in order to have the button render? From docs it doesn't seem so but maybe I have to do something DOM related. I'm not very familiar with JS

Comment: Hi Sam. It turns out if you have any content in your apple-sign-in-button div, it won't render the button (because it's worried there might already be one rendered). This is a bug and I'll make sure we get on fixing it, but in the meantime if you leave your div completely empty (not even spaces or a return character), then you should see the button show up.

Comment: Sooo...the Button now renders and when clicked brings up the Apple iCloud sign-in window however I'm still getting the same error and when I attempt to sign-in in the pop-up window I get two more of the same errors in the console. I've added the console.log of these errors here: http://hastebin.com/udopeputah.avrasm -- thanks for your help!

Comment: Just so I'm clear, you successfully sign in, the pop-up closes, and your app still thinks you're unauthenticated?

Comment: There is no indication that I've signed-in successfully, it appears that the sign-in is unsuccessful. After pressing sign-in (arrow) button, I get an activity indicator, the pop-up closes and I am not signed in. Screen remains as it was. Just a note, I am using MAMP to run on localhost:8888 - this may be of relevance?

Comment: Ah ha! The localhost is the issue. localhost is not currently supported as a valid domain with CloudKit Web Services, but it's also a known bug. If you use a tool to map a local server to a fake domain (e.g. foo.com) then it should resolve your issue for now.

Comment: Dave you were right - localhost didn't work but putting my files up through my hosting did... thanks again for all the help hope to carry this further!

Comment: Hi Dave - is it possible to use `document.write(exampleSignIn)` to create a `div id="apple-sign-in/out"` button... I've been trying but no luck. Thx

Answer (score 2):

Copying Dave Browning's comment to his answer out as a full-blown answer since that seems to be the issue for me:

> The localhost is the issue. localhost is not currently supported as a
>   valid domain with CloudKit Web Services, but it's also a known bug. If
>   you use a tool to map a local server to a fake domain (e.g. foo.com)
>   then it should resolve your issue for now